# Open Uri not opening url even though browser opens it

Tags: ruby, open-uri

I am trying to open a url with open-uri and when I open it from my browser, Safari, it takes me to the page in a second. However, when I try to open it with open-uri, it doesn't work. It says `Net::ReadTimeout: Net::ReadTimeout`, after a minute. It takes one second to open the url with my browser, but it doesn't work with open-uri ever. I have tried to increase the max timeout time but it doesn't work.

```
open(url).read
```

This is the code I use to open the url, and it doesn't work when I do it in the code.

Comment: what's the URL?

Comment: @Josh Brody http://stats.nba.com/stats/commonallplayers/?LeagueID=00&Season=2016-17&IsOnlyCurrentSeason=1

Comment: are you firing it as `http://stats.nba.com/stats/commonallplayers/?LeagueID=00&Season=2016-17&IsOnlyCurrentSeason=1` or just `stats.nba.com/stats/commonallplayers/?LeagueID=00&Season=2016-17&IsOnlyCurrentSeason=1`? Yes, you do have to specify protocol.

Comment: @JoshBrody I am using http

Comment: can you edit your post and share the piece of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like they're protecting their API against really vague requests.

```
`curl 'http://stats.nba.com/stats/commonallplayers?LeagueID=00&Season=2016-17&IsOnlyCurrentSeason=1' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36'`
```

will do it just fine.

Comment: great! how would I get the info in my code, though, because curl is a terminal command, right?